# Using other languages with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working with flutter for a couple of months now and it seems that there isn't really too much to work on an app for back-end or advanced functionality. I love using Flutter to help me design the UI but I want to use another language to help me do some other stuff. For example, I want to display a full-screen camera page (almost like Snapchat) or like send a direct message to another user through the app. Do I even need another language to do stuff like this? I am not an advanced programmer. I just want to create simple applications that can process and store a little bit of stuff.

Comment: These all functionalities you mentioned can be achieved by Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do the mentioned stuff in Flutter/Dart.
Check out Firebase Messaging for direct messages and SQLite to store information on user devices.

Comment: So, for example, if I wanted to create a food ordering app in which the owner can change the prices, add new menu items, etc. without the owner going back and hard coding it. What would I generally even use for this?

Comment: You're free to make two applications; one for the owner where he can have a user interface that allows him to change the database values from his phone and one to the other users where they visualize those values that only the owner can change with his application. Flutter/Dart is more than enough to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. For saving data locally,

You can use SqlFlite, a plugin with the help of which you can easily store and manage your database.

2. For saving data on the backend, so that other users can also access it when necessary, like the one you mentioned in a comment (..food ordering app)..you can use Firebase

Firebase has all you need.

Link to firebase :- https://firebase.google.com/

When your data is stored on a cloud, you don't need to hard code anything, for example, about the food ordering app you mentioned, you can make use of variables, in which you can store the values. So that when the owner changes the price, it gets updated.