# Is there a way to use Kotlin Code in flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I got some similar questions regarding to use any language with flutter but I am specific to use Kotlin or Java code in flutter.

I am working on Kotlin and Java. I want to make a cross platform app which can run on any device but I am not familiar with dart which is an official language for flutter. So is there any way that I can use Kotlin code in flutter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using other languages with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619752/using-other-languages-with-flutter)

Comment: @friedSyntax that question you've posted is quite bad and the answers there don't even really answer the question

Comment: @friedSyntax No. There is no sensible answer on the question you posted.

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan I did not post that question, just referencing your question to that post. sorry, btw. as far as I know flutter does not yet support any language except for dart.

Comment: I was talking about your reference you posted in your comment. Thank you for your concern. Your comment is valuable for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the following documentation.

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs

Also, if you are familiar with Java and Javascript, getting along with Flutter with dart language is not that hard. Good luck on your journey with Flutter.

Comment: Thanks I will checkout this link.